# errors while starting up tomcat

Tags: java, linux, tomcat

I am trying to setup Apache Tomcat on a Linux machine. I have installed tomcat 6 and java 7. Starting up tomcat gives:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Failed to reserve shared memory (errno = 22).
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Failed to reserve shared memory (errno = 1).
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Failed to reserve shared memory (errno = 1).
Error: SNMP ACL file not found: /srv/tomcat/conf/snmp.acl
```

Any clues regarding the above errors ?

Comment: Error relates to SNMP - your attempting to setup monitoring on your tomcat https://www.badllama.com/content/monitor-java-snmp. Helps to be able to walk before running

Comment: hope it helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566370/jvm-fails-to-allocate-xms-under-suse-sles10-x64-running-on-vmware-esx